# javascript onclicking buttons to give different divs

Tags: javascript

Im looking to improve my javascript, 1 thing I've noticed i do a lot is eval(string) and turn this in to a variable, I have an example here, with 2 cta's onclick to access different objects.
I'm looking for an alternative way rather than "eval" string all the time,

```js
//js
function test2(e){
  var x=e.value;
  var y=eval(x);
  var results = document.getElementById('results');
   results.innerHTML='name '+y.name+' age '+y.age


  }


 var tests={
   name:'lee',
    age:34
  }

  var test123={
    name:'leess',
    age:36

   }
```

```html
<button value="tests" onClick="test2(this)">Button</button>
<button value="test123" onClick="test2(this)">cta2</button>

<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: use `onClick` as `onclick`

Comment: How about passing a parameter in the function ? onClick="test2(this, "meaningful parameter)" ? is that what are looking for ? in the function verify the parameter and in one case your code should be something like this y = tests or y=test123 ?

Comment: @underscore both are valid

Answer (score 2):

You can give the javascript object directly in the onClick handler:

```js
//js
function test2(y){

  var results = document.getElementById('results');
   results.innerHTML='name '+y.name+' age '+y.age

  }


 var tests={
   name:'lee',
    age:34
  }

  var test123={
    name:'leess',
    age:36

   }
```

```html
<button value="tests" onClick="test2(tests)">Button</button>
<button value="test123" onClick="test2(test123)">cta2</button>

<div id="results"></div>
```